# [Search SERVER 2010] How to compare two dates with fulltext query?

Tags: search, search-results, search-express

I'm getting data with BDC in order to query it with Search Server. All is good, but I don't find how to compare two dates: my query looks like this:

ClaimDate =< 01/01/2011 AND [...]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide some more info? Compare ClaimDate and another date or compare ClaimDate dates between two values?

Comment: What did you try already and what were the results?

Comment: this is my query:

Comment: <QueryPacket Revision="1000" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Document.Document">
  <Query>
    <Context>
      <QueryText language='fr-FR' type='STRING'>ClaimDate < 01/01/2011</QueryText>
    </Context>
    <SupportedFormats>
      <Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Form.Form</Format>
    </SupportedFormats>
    <Range>
      [....]
    </Range>
    <TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>
    <Properties>
     [.....]
    </Properties>
  </Query>
</QueryPacket>

Comment: And always no results!

Comment: I changed ClaimDate < 01/01/2011 with ClaimDate > 01/01/2011 because it says "<" is an invalid tag header, but no responses again!

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you using:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query' Revision='1000'>
```

You query doesn't look like a fulltext query, but like a keyword query, it that correct?
A reference can be found here to build the different queries:
http://www.itidea.nl/index.php/example-of-using-the-spservices-search-web-service/

Probably the date format isn't correct either, I could be wrong, but I guess it has to be something like:
2011-04-08T13:45:47+02:00

Comment: I change my code with that:
<QueryPacket Revision="1000" xmlns="urn:Microsoft.Search.Query">
  <Query>
    <Context>
      <QueryText language='fr-FR' type='STRING'>
        ClaimDate > 2010-04-08T13:45:47+02:00</QueryText>
    </Context>
[....]
But no result found again!

Answer (score 0):

If managed property in search service, try this

```
ClaimDate:1/1/2012..1/1/2013
```

This should search for all files that have claim date between these two dates.